# Excessive CPU usage from mouse movement since upgrading to 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, mouse, 22.04, gnome-shell, cpu

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I have noticed that my mouse pointer is stuttering, so I investigated, and it seems like moving the mouse causes >90% CPU usage spikes, when the load returns to the normal range as soon as the mouse is kept still (no other programs running).

When Firefox is open, the CPU usage is consistently high, with different cores spiking at different times, even when only two or three tabs are open, and no media are playing.

`htop` tells me that it is almost exclusively `gnome-shell` that is consuming processing power in both cases.

Does anyone have an idea how this issue could be resolved?

EDIT: My CPU is a Intel [i7-10510U](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/196449/intel-core-i710510u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html)

Comment: add some CPU specs please.

Comment: Right sorry. I have an Intel i7-10510U. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/196449/intel-core-i710510u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: Have you tried using X11 instead of Wayland to see if the problem persists?

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet, since I'd rather not resort to X11 if I can help it at all, as I prefer the per-app-isolation of Wayland. I will try a fresh installation of Ubuntu and see if this does something to fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can Use Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead, because they are really light weight. If you wish not to switch, Then switch to the rather more buggy, `Ubuntu on xorg`. During login, in the menu with the small gear icon, there is an option for ubuntu on org option.

Since you haven't mentioned any CPU specs, I'm assuming you have a low end CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have an Intel i7-10510U, so it should be more than able to handle Ubuntu with a Gnome Environment.